# Use one InputStream as source for multiple higher level InputStreams (like BufferedReader, DataInputStream)

Tags: java, tcp, stream

i was just wandering if this was a good or bad idea:

```
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
```

Now I'd like to read from the BufferedReader. If a certain command (just a string) arrives, I'd like to continue reading from the DataInputStream.

Does this work? If yes, is it considered good or bad practice?

Comment: This won't compile: You can't create a `(Data)InputStream` (byte-based) from an `InputStreamReader` (character-based) (only the other way round: stream to reader). At runtime, it will most likely still fail due to buffering issues -- what to you want to do with the `BufferedReader` and `DataInputStream`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I think your example is broken in terms of what is a reader and what is an input stream, but I get the question anyways)

You can do things like that, but you need to know exactly how each component is behaving with regards to buffering.

The socket input stream you are working from will only allow you to read a certain byte once (checkout `InputStream.markSupported()`). You can wrap that input stream in a `BufferedInputStream` that effectively reads some bytes ahead but also adds the functionality to do a `mark()` and `reset()`.

This means that any reader/input stream on top of the `BufferedInputStream` can read ahead, mark, skip back etc. But here you need to be careful so that you don't add another layer of "buffers" - i.e. a `BufferedReader` > `InputStreamReader` > `BufferedInputStream` > `InputStream`.

So the answer is yes, it can be made to work, just know the exact behaviour of every component (I often see people throwing in `BufferedXXX` just for the hell of it).

In your example I would do:

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "utf-8"); // consider char encoding
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will not work.

Buffered reader reads buffers and parses them as lines. So if for example there is 2 and half lines available it will probably move the marker of payload stream to that position. Now you read line and then decide to read long value using DataInputStream. The code will try to read this value from the position of payload stream (after 2.5 lines). But you really wanted to read the number after the first line.

I think this example explains also why this idea not a good practice. Java streams implement decorator (wrapper) pattern. Each stream adds its own functionality. Attempt to wrap the same "real" stream with several wrappers looks like attempt to break this encapsulation.